# Vector of pointer member functions c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have the following code:

```
        typedef bool (A::*rule)(shared_ptr<Node >, shared_ptr<Node> )  ;
```

when initilaising the class A object, I run the following code

```
        v_ = vector<rule>();
        v_.push_back(A::memberFunction);
```

I have also tried with  v_.push_back(&A::memberFunction) as this seemed more logical to me, but was
advised against on the forums. I also get an error message

This is as suggested by the many topics on the matter. However, I get the following error

```
       non-const lvalue reference to type 'value_type' (aka 'bool (boost::shared_ptr<Node>, boost::shared_ptr<Node>)')
  cannot bind to a temporary of type '<bound member function type>'
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (or optionally [Boost function library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html)).

Comment: using `v_.push_back(&A::memberFunction)` works for me with gcc 4.7.3

Comment: Mmmm doesn't seem to work with Clang. Odd.

Comment: What's the exact signature of A::member_function?

Comment: What is `v_ = vector<rule>();` line? How is `v_` declared?

Comment: Version with taking address works for me: http://ideone.com/K0Bw6q

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, fails with the same error. I am restricted to using Clang.

Comment: You were asked two questions. Instead of answering them you keep saying "doesn't work". Time to test new closing dialog.

Comment: _"but was advised against on the forums"_ You should find a better forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also tried with v_.push_back(&A::memberFunction) as this seemed more logical to me, but was advised against on the forums.

I don't know what forums were those. Forming a pointer-to-member has a single valid syntax, and it is `& classname::membername`.  All elements mandatory.

Use that consistently and post code and error message for that version should the problem persist.

Comment: Done that, as indicated above, but still obtain the same error. I am restricted to using CLang, seems to work fine with GCC

Comment: we can't help you without a complete example to look at

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles under llvm/clang 4.2 (As @balog-pal said, the `&` is mandatory before `classname::membername`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Node {};
struct A
{
    bool rule(std::shared_ptr<Node>, std::shared_ptr<Node>)
        {return true;}
};

typedef bool (A::*rule)(std::shared_ptr<Node>, std::shared_ptr<Node> );

int main(int, const char**)
{
    std::vector<rule> v;
    v.push_back(&A::rule);
    return 0;
}
```

Please post a full not-compiling example, your issue must be hidden somewhere else.